# Search for listings on a german website in a given postal code, return an excel spreadsheet with details from X listings

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation

I'm a newbie and originally I wanted to write some code to automate getting to the results page of a site that lists apartments for workers.

Then I got some inspiration and wanted to automate getting the data from each entry as well.

It works and it saves me a lot of time, but it does seem like I went to too much trouble for what it does?

I was already advised that I should use more functions/define more functions, but I guess that'd just make seven functions? How would that be helpful in comparison to the 7 blocks of code I have?

I am also convinced hat this is the hackiest thing I could have done and it does not seem like a good solution at all.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

#prepare the excel workbook
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#give the driver the site to load and ask the user for the german postal code and number of results
webpage = r"https://mein-monteurzimmer.de"
print('Prosim vnesi zeljeno mesto')
searchterm = input()
print('Prosim vnesi stevilo rezultatov.')
number_of_results = int(input())
    

driver.get(webpage)
#go through the steps required to get to the results page
GDPR = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.primary")
GDPR.click()

sbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Adresse, PLZ oder Ort eingeben']")
sbox.send_keys(searchterm)

driver.implicitly_wait(2)

addressXpath = "//div[contains(text(),'"+searchterm+"')]"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(addressXpath).click()

submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/cpagearea/section/div[2]/div/section[1]/div/div[1]/section/form/button")
submit.click()

First_result = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/cresultcontainer/div/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div")
First_result.click()
#iterate through the results as many times as the user demanded
i = 0
while (i < number_of_results):

    Result_page = driver.current_url

    stran = requests.get(driver.current_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(stran.content, 'html.parser')
    #find and extract the relevant info for each listing
    ime = soup.find("dd", itemprop="name")
    if ime:
        print(ime.text)
        c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=1)
        c1.value = ime.text
        
    ulica = soup.find("dd", itemprop="streetAddress")
    if ulica:
        print(ulica.text)
        c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=2)
        c1.value = ulica.text
            
    postna_stevilka = soup.find("span", itemprop="postalCode")
    if postna_stevilka:
        print(postna_stevilka.text)
        c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=3)
        c1.value = postna_stevilka.text
        
    kraj = soup.find("span", itemprop="addressLocality")
    if kraj:
        print(kraj.text)
        c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=4)
        c1.value = kraj.text
        
    tel = soup.find("dd", itemprop="telephone")
    if tel:
        print(tel.text)
        c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=5)
        c1.value = tel.text
        
    spletna_stran = soup.find("dd", itemprop="url")
    if spletna_stran:
        print(spletna_stran.text)
        c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=6)
        c1.value = spletna_stran.text
     #this specific one doesn't work as they used the same class and name for
     #both mobile and landline. Need to figure this out.
     #However, if there is no landline, at least the mobile number is extracted.
    mobil = soup.find("dd", itemprop="telephone").parent.find_next_siblings()
    if mobil:
        print(mobil.text)
        c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=7)
        c1.value = mobil.text
            
     
 #click through to the next result
    next_entry = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/chousingdetail/div/div[2]/div[1]/nav/div/div[2]/a[2]/i")
    next_entry.click()
    i +=1


#once all the results have been worked through, save the workbook to this directory:
 wb.save("[Directory to save to]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Localisation

This:

```
#give the driver the site to load and ask the user for the german postal code and number of results
```

and this:

```
print('Prosim vnesi stevilo rezultatov.')
```

are both great. The former uses English for code, which is generally advised; and the latter uses a localised language (Slovenian?) for user-facing content.

These should be avoided:

```
ulica = soup.find
postna_stevilka = soup.find
```

and use English instead (street, postcode). For better or worse, English is the de-facto language of international programming, and using it for your variable names will make your code more legible for collaborators and colleagues.

### General approach

Always when thinking about scraping a website, look at the network or traffic tab of your browser's developer tools. In this case it shows:

```
https://mein-monteurzimmer.de/api/v2/search
```

That's an API that you can call into with Requests, which will be more simpler and more efficient than Selenium.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will keep in mind to look for API first next time. 

And the point about using English for variables makes a lot of sense going forward!

Comment: Oh, and good job on recognizing the language. :D